# Adding computer vision datasets?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, computer-vision, resource-management

I find having ResourceData/Objects for machine learning datasets to be extremely useful, with their "TrainingData", "TestData" properties:

[image]

Right now there's only a handful:

[image]

And even fewer for computer vision datasets:

[image]

I'd like to turn the small [CALTECH Faces challenge](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/html-files/archive.html) dataset of 465 images into a dataset as `ResourceObject["CALTECH-Faces"]`, and then publish it for others, can anyone show me how to do this?

Comment: From the documentation, it seems that you can define your own resource object using `ResourceObject [assoc]`.

Comment: But how to publish it for others?

Answer (score 8):

It seems that [Wolfram Data Repository](https://datarepository.wolframcloud.com/) can be used to share data using `ResourceObject`. Here is a simple example:

```
mytrainingData = RandomSample[ResourceData[ResourceObject["MNIST"], "TrainingData"], 10];
```

I'm trying to make `mytrainingData` into a ResourceObject so that we can access the data like

```
resource = ResourceObject[...];
data = ResourceData[resource,"mytrainingData"];
```

To do that, we first fill the descriptions in the template created by

```
CreateNotebook["DataResource"]
```

[image]

Then in the data "Resource Content" section, specify the data content

```
$$Object["FullContent"] = 
  DataResource`$$ContentConversion@<|
    "mytrainingData" -> mytrainingData|>;
```

Now we can deploy the data to the cloud using the button, which returns a `CloudObject`:

> CloudObject[https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/a701ff40-d42b-4e08-a324-df0c6906887c]

We can then set this `CloudObject` to be publically accessible:

```
obj=CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/a701ff40-d42b-4e08-a324-df0c6906887c"]
SetPermissions[obj, "Public"]
```

Now this data set can be accessed similarly with the built in data

```
resource = ResourceObject[CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/a701ff40-d42b-4e08-a324-df0c6906887c"]]
data = ResourceData[resource, "mytrainingData"]
```

or

```
resource = ResourceObject["f49415d4-56c2-4892-90d2-330d1e444db8"]
data = ResourceData[resource, "mytrainingData"]
```

Comment: What do you actually need to make `CreateNotebook["DataResource"]` work? Mathematica 11 does not understand it...

Comment: @leosenko I think you have to use the newest version of Mathematica (11.1.1)